# Allocating the total value of a field to others based on Gross Revenue

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am trying to allocate the total value of a channel to others based on Gross Revenue in Power Query. The data source is from SQL, a query that i made to recover the data from the channel and gross revenue.

In this case I am trying to allocate the total value of channel C (Total of C = 4) to A and B, based on its Gross Revenue.

This a dummy table, simplified from the thousands of rows and several columns that I have:

| Channel | GR |
| --- | --- |
| A | 5 |
| A | 1 |
| B | 10 |
| B | 4 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 3 |

The table from PowerQuery that I expect is as following:

| Channel | GR | GR2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 6 |
| A | 1 | 1.2 |
| B | 10 | 12 |
| B | 4 | 4.8 |
| C | 1 | 0 |
| C | 3 | 0 |

I can do it in Excel, as it follows - however, as I said before, I cannot use it because the data source comes from SQL and want to present several graphs and information about this table in PowerBI [Formula used in Excel, if it helps some way =IF(G2="C";0;H2+SUMIFS(H:H;G:G;"C")*(H2/(SUM($H$2:$H$18)-SUMIFS(H:H;G:G;"C"))))] :

[Solving the problem using Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3fHK.png)

I do not understand M languange enough to replicate this formula and everything I tried it just results in Erros in each line.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**TL;DR: Trying to allocate the total of the channel value to the other channel based on GR**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in powerquery

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Channel", type text}, {"GR", Int64.Type}}),
#"NotCFiltered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Channel] <> "C")),
#"CFiltered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Channel] = "C")),
#"Added Custom" =  Table.AddColumn(#"NotCFiltered Rows", "GR2", each ( [GR]/ List.Sum(#"NotCFiltered Rows"[GR])) * List.Sum(#"CFiltered Rows"[GR]) + [GR] ,type number)
in  #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: I copied your solution and in this dummy data it worked except the total of GR2 should be equal as total of GR and your solution it is not

Comment: I think the add column code should be as follows: = Table.AddColumn(#"NotCFiltered Rows", "GR2", each ( [GR]/ List.Sum(#"NotCFiltered Rows"[GR])) * List.Sum(#"CFiltered Rows"[GR]) + [GR] ,type number)

Comment: Okay, I think it works!

I added some more dummy columns on the table and it continues to work - I am going to try on my large dataset but the solution for this question is answered!

Comment: Don't forget to mark as solved and upvote if your problem is solved

Comment: Okay, I am going to mark as solved, thanks a lot!

Comment: @DavidBacci, if you cold post an answer to mark as the right solution it would be great!

I cannot mark a comment as the solution or upvote it

Comment: @horseyride's answer is the right solution. He will update it when he sees the code change. My contribution was minimal.

Comment: Ha! thanks David. I guess I didn't check my output of the last part before leaving the house